# I don't understand the 'left' and 'right' functions in visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently learning about functions in visual basic but i can't sesem to understand the 'left' or 'right' function

This is the definition I have been provided with in my handbook:

[image: click to see image]

I don't currently have any example codes

Could somebody explain what exactly these functions do in a code more simply and if they're kind enough, include an example?

Comment: Try it: supply two arguments and see the result. No rocket science.

Comment: It says what the functions do right in the fourth column of that picture. And these functions are explained in the original documentation. Please don't ask us do write new documentation just for you.

Comment: Please read the [VBA Language Reference in the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/visual-basic-language-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

### Explanations

The left function can be used to get the selected length of characters in a string from the left. You can use it with the following syntax.

> Left(yourString, length)

As an example, the following code

```
Left("Run clever boy, and remember me", 14) 'Result is: Run clever boy
```

Will return **Run clever boy** as a result since the **14** first characters of the string sent as parameter are **Run clever boy**.

The right function does exactly the same except it selects the characters not from the beginning of your string but from the end.

> Right(yourString, length)

As an example, the following code

```
Right("Run clever boy, and remember me", 11)
```

Will return **remember me** because the **11** last characters of the string that you sent as parameter are **remember me**.

---

### In short

**First argument**: Your string

**Second argument**: The amount of characters to select in that string.

Use the **Left** function to select characters from the beginning of your string.

Use the **Right** function to select characters from the end of your string.

Answer (score 0):

See the codes below

```
Dim testString As String = "The*quick+brown*fox."
Dim left, right As String

'Get the LEFT 9 characters.>>

left = testString.Substring(0, 9)

MessageBox.Show(left)

'Get the right 5 characters.>>

right = testString.Substring(testString.Length - 5, 5)

MessageBox.Show(right)
```

try run this code will understand clearly